# three.js change mesh from scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to change a mesh from a group, trriged by a button.

I'm loading an external .obj file:

```
loader.load( obj, function ( object ) {

    createScene( object, mod.tipo, pid, cor.replace("#","0x") );

});
```

and add on a group

```
function createScene( geometry, name, id, cor ) {

    geometry.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                specular: 0xffffff,
                shininess: 10,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/3d/js/texturas/white.jpg'),
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading
            } );

            material.color.setHex(cor);

            child.material = material;

            group.add( child );     

        }
```

and add this group in a scene: `scene.add( group )`

to change i set de visible of my mesh to false. But a want to remove it from scene and group.

I already try `scene.remove('name')` and `scene.remove(mesh)` but didnt work.

Someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
var toRemove = scene.getNodeByName ( 'name', true );
if (toRemove !== undefined)
    scene.remove ( toRemove );
```

which searches in your scene for a node named `name` and then removes the resulting node from the scene.

Comment: i have this error : TypeError: undefined is not a function

on this line:

console.log( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer', THREE.REVISION );

Comment: I think the problem is i'm using a group, or better, i tring do delete a mesh from the scene and not form the goup. I dont know how to delete a mesh from a group

Comment: is that line `console.log ...` part of your question

Comment: you would delete a mesh from a group the same way. instead of searching in the `scene` for the object to remove, you would search in your `group`.

Answer (score 0):

I get a solution:

In my case i was using a group to join the meshes and rotate all of them to start position.

First i have to add the mashes directly in the scene. I could'n make it work on a group
Second i have a global variable that contain an array of all meshes. And as was tring to remove use this reference. I have to change this logic.

So i create this function:

var clearScene = function(name) {
    var objsToRemove = scene.children;

```
for (var t = 0; t<objsToRemove.length; t++){

    if (objsToRemove[t] instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

      if (objsToRemove[t].name = name) {
        scene.remove(objsToRemove[t]);
        break;
      }

    }

}
```

}

it goes on each meshe looking for the mashe i want to delete. and simply call the remove frome the scene.

this works for me.

I have to change my group logic and mabe rotate mesh by mashe to default position, i think that i will have a better performance